# Why jQuery.isArray() method doesn't output true for the selector: $("span")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

```
<div>
    <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
</div>  

var $spans = $("span")
var x = [1,2,3];
alert($.isArray($spans)) // false
alert($.isArray(x)) // true
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9m27Lxyz/

I would like to select with jQuery selector all the span tags. Why this selector: $("span") returns me an object? I need to use array methods such as shift(), or splice() on this span selector. What shall I do, so this selector would return me normal JS array object?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.shift.call($spans)`](https://jsfiddle.net/9m27Lxyz/1/) ...or... [`jQuery.prototype.shift = Array.prototype.shift;`, then just `$spans.shift()`](https://jsfiddle.net/9m27Lxyz/2/)

Comment: Though in the case of `.shift()`, it would probably make more sense to use the built-in `$spans = $spans.slice(1)` unless you really need to mutate the original object.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I will use toArray() method.

$spans.toArray().

Is it good practice?

[edit: not quite. Because I can not use jQuery methods. So I would need to switch between jquery spans and js spans...]